# How to use URL in route in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I create route in `web.php` but i need to edit this route.

In `route.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'flight'], function () {
        Route::get('/{fromCity}-{toCity}/{fromDate?}/{toDate?}/{adult?}-{child?}-{infant?}', ['as' => 'flight', 'uses' => 'Site\Flight\IndexController@index'])
            ->where([
                'fromCity' => '[A-Z]+',
                'toCity' => '[A-Z]+',
                'fromDate' => '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}',
                'toDate' => '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}',
                'adult' => '[0-9]+',
                'child' => '[0-9]+',
                'infant' => '[0-9]+'
            ]);
    });
```

It route work for just this `URL`:

`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON/2017-02-11/2017-02-16/1-0-0`

But i need use this `URL:

`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON/2017-02-11/1-0-0`

Or:

`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON`

How to edit route for work out these three `URL`?

Comment: Why don't you pass `fromDate, toDate` etc as query string?

Comment: Hi @mrabbani, For SEO. the user did not choose the date, today's date is recorded.

Comment: Why don't you handle those variables inside a controller? using `isset()` to check if they are filled in (and `explode()` by '-')

Comment: Hi @Thomas , Please explain more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use several routes to achieve this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'flight/{fromCity}-{toCity}'], function () {
    // Matches: /flight/IKA-LON
    Route::get('/', 'YourController@flights');

    // Matches: /flight/IKA-LON/2017-02-11/2017-02-16/1-0-0
    Route::get('{fromDate}/{toDate}/{adult}-{child}-{infant}', 'YourController@flightsFromTo');

    // Matches: /flight/IKA-LON/2017-02-11/1-0-0
    Route::get('{fromDate}/{adult}-{child}-{infant}', 'YourController@flightsFrom');
});
```

The group allows you to match `{fromCity}` and `{toCity}` in all routes.

In your controller, if you're going to be displaying the same things and running the same functionality in each of your routes you could create a method in your controller that each method calls:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function doFlights($fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate, $toDate, $adults, $children, $infants)
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }

    public function flights($fromCity, $toCity)
    {
        return $this->doFlights($fromCity, $toCity, date('Y-m-d'), date('Y-m-d'), 1, 0, 0);
    }

    public function flightsFromTo($fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate, $toDate, $adults, $children, $infants)
    {
        return $this->doFlights($fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate, $toDate, $adults, $children, $infants);
    }

    public function flightsFrom($fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate, $adults, $children, $infants)
    {
        return $this->doFlights($fromCity, $toCity, $fromDate, $fromDate, $adults, $children, $infants);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need one route for 3 url.

Comment: Why? I think you'll be hard pressed to manage that, unless you were to do as @Thomas has suggested above and try to parse the different parts out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't jump over **optional** parameters. You can leave blank only last one. But middle ones need to be there. Or you can leave all blank, or last two. **You can't jump over**.

I suggest you to use default values. For example:

`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON/2017-02-11/2017-02-16/1-0-0`
`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON/2017-02-11/NOW/1-0-0`
`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON/NOW/NOW/1-0-0`

You can use **NOW** or **TODAY**. Or what you think is most appropriate in your code.

---

Or use different URL structure:

`http://localhost:8000/flight/IKA-LON?from=2017-02-11&to=2017-02-16&adult=1&child=0&infant=0`

It's not clean enough, but you have no choice. You should use first or second approach.

Comment: Hi, Oh no... How can I URL all three I use?

Comment: I didn't get your question. What do you mean "How can I URL"?

Comment: sorry, I'm not good in English. How to use it 3 url in route or routes? without NOW or TODAY ?

Comment: You can't generate url in that way as you wish. You need to use NOW/TODAY placeholders, or Query Params structure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for an explaination on my comment, here is a simplified answer:

**In web.php (or api.php)**

```
Route::get('flight', 'FlightController@index');
```

**In FlightController**

```
function index(Request $request) {
    $url_path = str_replace ($request->url(), '', $request->fullUrl());
    $url_path_array = explode( '/' , $url_path);
    foreach ($url_path_array as $part) {
        // do something with the parts (based on regex or order)

    // flight regex: 
    $re1 = '/([A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3})/';
    // adult etc:
    $re2 = '/([0-1]{1}-[0-1]{1}-[0-1]{1})/';
    // from and to 
    $re3 = '/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/';

    }
}
```

**REGEX**

```
((?P<from>[A-Z]{3})-(?P<to>[A-Z]{3}))|((?P<adult>[0-1]{1})-(?P<child>[0-1]{1})-(?P<infant>[0-1]{1}))|(?P<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})
```

[regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/Q93Pt3/2)

Comment: Yes, but you can handle the parts with regex for example to determine what type of url is passed! If the string in `$part` is `([A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3})` it's a flight part. if it's parseble to a datetime it's from etc.